# Selenium and geckodriver - Open Firefox Full Screen

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am attempting to use the "gecko" webdriver (.17 I believe) with Selenium (v.3.4.0) to open an older version of Firefox (52.9.0 ESR) in fullscreen (NOT maximized). However, even after reviewing some questions on this website, as well as performing other research, I am still unable to open Firefox in fullscreen. My code is very simple:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver");
    String user = args[0];
    String pass = args[1];

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

    // options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
    // options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    // options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);

    driver.get(BASE_URL);
    driver.findElement(By.name("user")).sendKeys(user);
    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(pass);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

}
```

I have tried the following:

- Using a custom profile and loading two different extensions (AutoFullscreen and MPT Fullscreen).
- Using `driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.F11);` (throws `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: sendKeysToActiveElement`
  )
- Looking for a command line argument to pass to the browser.

I can get this working in Chromium by simply setting an option, but have had no success with Firefox. How might I get it to work with this browser? I am using the older version of Firefox because this is running on a Rasperry PI and that seems to be the latest version supported on the device.

Thanks.

EDIT:
    Output from `driver.manage().window().fullscreen()`:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Dec 11, 2018 9:07:29 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: fullscreenWindow
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version: '4.14.79-v7+', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.GRnhrulj1j6l, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, page load=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.9.0, platformVersion=4.14.79-v7+, moz:processID=1076.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
Session ID: 6633ed83-9a19-4e5c-9229-5fadef8a83ce
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:694)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.fullscreen(RemoteWebDriver.java:929)
    at com.midamcorp.kblogin.Entry.main(Entry.java:31)
```

Comment: Why not use driver.manage().windows().fullscreen(); ?

Comment: If using custom browser profile, firefox should "remember" it was in full screen mode in last session. So I guess firefox wasn't in full screen mode when last session was closed or there is something wrong with loading the custom profile.

Comment: @kushal.8 It is not supported for the geckodriver/Selenium/browser version combination (not sure which is the problem), but it gives an exception.

Comment: please share your selenium/geckodriver/browserversion; also the error description

Comment: @kushal.8 The versions are in the opening post (.17 for geckodriver I believe, Selenium 3.4.0, Firefox ESR 52.9.0 ESR). I have added the stack that results from calling driver.manage().window().fullscreen() to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @KellyMarchewa : as per this post here :https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/766 fullScreen support was added to Firefox version 55 onwards

Comment: @kushal.8 Thank you very much for the information. Looks like I might not be able to accomplish what I want, as I don't think there is anyway to get Firefox 55 or great on a Pi. But thanks again, saves me some time at least. :)

Comment: you are welcome :)